# Java - Convert List into Map & merge duplicate key data internally

Tags: java, java-stream

I've `List` containing data a VO, say `DataVO` like:

```
DataVO 1: 1, abcd, efgh
DataVO 2: 1, pqrs, wxyz
DataVO 3: 2, hello, letsgo
```

I want to create a `Map` with key as first element and the `List` as the value.

```
Map<Integer, List<DataVO>> myDataMap
```

So the contents will be like:

`myDataMap.get(1)` is List containing `1, abcd, efgh` & `1, pqrs, wxyz`

`myDataMap.get(2)` is List containing `2, hello, letsgo`

Right now I'm doing it like this:

```
Map<Integer, List<DataVO>> myDataMap = new HashMap<>();
dataVoList.forEach(dataVo -> {
    int id = dataVo.getId();
    if (myDataMap.containsKey(id)) {
        myDataMap.get(id).add(dataVo);
    } else {
        myDataMap.put(id, new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(dataVo)));
    }
});
```

How to optimize this?

I tired using stream, like this:

```
dataVoList.stream().collect(toMap(Data::id, ....));
```

But it gives duplicate key error.

And if I use merge attribute, then it only keeps one element. (As explained [here](https://javabycode.com/java-8-tutorial/java-8-list-to-map-duplicate-keys.html))

Please suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `groupingBy`:

```
Map<Integer, List<DataVO>> myDataMap =
    dataVoList.stream()
              .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(DataVO::getId));
```